# C Filling Chess board with T and H, somehow there are gaps and only 7 rows instead of 8

Tags: c, chess

I had my previous question closed as it was too broad, so I decided to write code in parts and only ask something if I had a specific problem.

My code so far sees what parts of chess board are filled with knights (in code 'H') and fill the parts they dominate with 'T'. The goal is to fill all parts of the chess board with 'H' and 'T' and to have not dominated blocks left at '0'. Then the program tests if all the fields are either 'T' or 'H', if yes returns 1, if no 0. Then it prints out the chess board.

However it only prints out 7 rows (still 8 columns though), and even though I filled the board with 12 knights that are in position to dominate the entire board, somehow there are still 0s left. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int filling(char array[7][7])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] == 'H')
            {
                if(i-1>-1 && j+2<8) array[i-1][j+2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j+2<8) array[i+1][j+2]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j+1<8) array[i-2][j+1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j+1<8) array[i+2][j+1]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j-1>-1) array[i-2][j-1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j-1>-1) array[i+2][j-1]='T';
                if(i-1>-1 && j-2>-1) array[i-1][j-2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j-2>-1) array[i+1][j-2]='T';

            }
        }
    }
}
int checking(char array[7][7])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] != 'H' && array[i][j] != 'T')
                return 0;
            else return 1;
        }
   }
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char board[7][7];
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            board[i][j] = '0';
    }
    board[2][1] = 'H';
    board[2][2] = 'H';
    board[3][2] = 'H';
    board[5][2] = 'H';
    board[6][2] = 'H';
    board[5][3] = 'H';
    board[2][4] = 'H';
    board[1][5] = 'H';
    board[2][5] = 'H';
    board[4][5] = 'H';
    board[5][5] = 'H';
    board[5][6] = 'H';
    filling(board);
    if(checking(board) == 1) printf ("Works");
    else printf ("Doesnt work");
   for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What do you think is the problem here? Am I doing something worng?
Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: Made a mistake not making sure that horses dont get changed into 'T's. Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int pildymas(char array[7][7])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] == 'H')
            {
                if(i-1>-1 && j+2<8 && array[i-1][j+2]!='H') array[i-1][j+2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j+2<8 && array[i+1][j+2]!='H') array[i+1][j+2]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j+1<8 && array[i-2][j+1]!='H') array[i-2][j+1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j+1<8 && array[i+2][j+1]!='H') array[i+2][j+1]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j-1>-1 && array[i-2][j-1]!='H') array[i-2][j-1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j-1>-1 && array[i+2][j-1]!='H') array[i+2][j-1]='T';
                if(i-1>-1 && j-2>-1 && array[i-1][j-2]!='H') array[i-1][j-2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j-2>-1 && array[i+1][j-2]!='H') array[i+1][j-2]='T';

            }
        }
    }
}
int tikrinimas(char array[7][7])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] != 'H' && array[i][j] != 'T')
                return 0;
            else return 1;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char board[7][7];
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            board[i][j] = '0';
    }
    board[2][1] = 'H';
    board[2][2] = 'H';
    board[3][2] = 'H';
    board[5][2] = 'H';
    board[6][2] = 'H';
    board[5][3] = 'H';
    board[2][4] = 'H';
    board[1][5] = 'H';
    board[2][5] = 'H';
    board[4][5] = 'H';
    board[5][5] = 'H';
    board[5][6] = 'H';
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    pildymas(board);
    if(tikrinimas(board) == 1) printf ("Veikia");
    else printf ("neveikia");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I notice people say that my array doesnt have enough size. I was under impression that an array A[2] will have A[0] A[1] and A[2] spots, is this wrong?

Thank you for your help, I am pretty sure that I will be back tonight though :)

**EXTRA QUESTION**

I have it all working now with filling and testing, but I need to find a way to fill the board with all the possible combinations of 12 horses, and the only way I have in mind is creating a for cycle that is 12 levels deep, meaning it would have to do 64^12 cycles. Is there any other way I could try every possible positioning of 12 horses on a 8x8 board? My plan is to take a position, then test if it fits, if so save it, and then try another one until all the positions are done. As far as I know there are only 1\2 combinations of 12 horses to dominate all fields on the board.

Comment: One too many in `for (i = 0;i < 8;i++)`. Your indexes are `0-6` for `array[7]`...

Comment: "7 rows instead of 8" ... eh ... `array[7][7]` ?

Comment: Dont all arrays have 0th space like array[0], making Array[number] have number+1 spaces?

Comment: @Gytis No. Indexes start from 0, that's true. But the last valid index is (n-1). So for an array declared as `a[n]` the valid indices are 0 to (n-1) with the total number of elements being n.

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Code with everything fixed and working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int pildymas(char array[8][8])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] == 'H')
            {
                if(i-1>-1 && j+2<8 && array[i-1][j+2]!='H') array[i-1][j+2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j+2<8 && array[i+1][j+2]!='H') array[i+1][j+2]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j+1<8 && array[i-2][j+1]!='H') array[i-2][j+1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j+1<8 && array[i+2][j+1]!='H') array[i+2][j+1]='T';
                if(i-2>-1 && j-1>-1 && array[i-2][j-1]!='H') array[i-2][j-1]='T';
                if(i+2<8 && j-1>-1 && array[i+2][j-1]!='H') array[i+2][j-1]='T';
                if(i-1>-1 && j-2>-1 && array[i-1][j-2]!='H') array[i-1][j-2]='T';
                if(i+1<8 && j-2>-1 && array[i+1][j-2]!='H') array[i+1][j-2]='T';

            }
        }
    }
}
int tikrinimas(char array[8][8])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < 8;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] != 'H' && array[i][j] != 'T')
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char board[8][8];
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            board[i][j] = '0';
    }
    board[2][1] = 'H';
    board[2][2] = 'H';
    board[3][2] = 'H';
    board[5][2] = 'H';
    board[6][2] = 'H';
    board[5][3] = 'H';
    board[2][4] = 'H';
    board[1][5] = 'H';
    board[2][5] = 'H';
    board[4][5] = 'H';
    board[5][5] = 'H';
    board[5][6] = 'H';
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    pildymas(board);
    if(tikrinimas(board) == 1) printf (" \n Veikia");
    else printf ("\n neveikia");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Solved my problem. Here are the things I had to change:
1) Increase array size by 1 in both dimensions.
2) Make sure my 'H's dont get overwritten by 'T's.
3) In checking function I made a mistake of including return 1 in a cycle, which therefore would print out that it works as long as the first value was working. I left return 0 in cycle, because as long as there is one spot empty, it doesnt work, but I moved return 1 after the cycle, as if only there are no empty spaces it should count as a success.

Comment: Glad you got it working. It's a good idea to answer your own question. But code only answers are discouraged. Suggest you take out the "FINAL EDIT" section from your question and put it here in your answer instead.

Comment: Curiously in `pildymas`, I note all your `if` logic results in doing no more than `if (array[i][j] != 'H') array[i][j] = 'T';`. Is there something else taking place?

Comment: Well If the function finds, that the space is taken by a knight ('H'), only then it fills out all the 8 spaces a knight can take with 'T', therefore I only need to check if the space is not out of bounds.

To put it more simply, upon finding a knight in the chess board, the function checks all 8 other positions the knight can take, and if they are not out of bounds and are not already taken by a knight, it fills the position with 'T' for taken, as a knight can take it in one move.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what type of dominance you are attempting to create on the board, but to get your indexes within the correct bounds for a `7x7` array, you will need something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { DIM = 7 };

void filling (char (*array)[DIM])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            if (array[i][j] != 'H') 
                array[i][j] = 'T';
}

int checking (char (*array)[DIM])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            if (array[i][j] != 'H' && array[i][j] != 'T')
                return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main (void) {

    int i, j;
    char board[DIM][DIM] = {{0}};

    board[2][1] = 'H';
    board[2][2] = 'H';
    board[3][2] = 'H';
    board[5][2] = 'H';
    board[6][2] = 'H';
    board[5][3] = 'H';
    board[2][4] = 'H';
    board[1][5] = 'H';
    board[2][5] = 'H';
    board[4][5] = 'H';
    board[5][5] = 'H';
    board[5][6] = 'H';

    filling (board);

    if (checking (board) == 1)
        printf ("Works");
    else
        printf ("Doesnt work");

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printf ("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            printf ("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chess
Works
T T T T T T T
T T T T T H T
T H H T H H T
T T H T T T T
T T T T T H T
T T H H T H H
T T H T T T T
```

Or the beauty in properly eliminating all magic numbers from your code and using proper constants is changing `1` number is all that is needed to create an `8x8`. e.g.

```
enum { DIM = 8 };
```

And now the output is:

```
$ ./bin/chess
Works
T T T T T T T T
T T T T T H T T
T H H T H H T T
T T H T T T T T
T T T T T H T T
T T H H T H H T
T T H T T T T T
T T T T T T T T
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already solved my problem and posted the answer here.

However, now I have another question, and maybe in order to avoid creating a separate question, I could ask you here. I need to fill the board with 12 horses in all the possible ways, however I dont know how to do that, the only way I have in mind is using 12 for cycles, but that would be 64^12 cycles, and I think there must be better ways. Maybe you have any ideas?

By the way, by dominate I mean all the board is controlled by knigts, all spaces are either taken by a knight or a knight can move to them

Comment: Well, each knight is constrained to move `2` forward and `1` left/right. so it would seem you could simply loop `i`, `j` and check the possible `[i +/- 2][j +/- 1]` and `[j +/- 2][i +/- 1]` combinations that stay within the board.